# Supporting a different look for the same View for the corresponding API level in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, apk

I have built a test application in Android with minimum API level as 8 in which I want to implement the following :

I have a toggle button which looks somewhat like this :

[image]

This as you know is the default design of toggle buttons in API level 8.
But I want my UI to be adaptive to the API level the application is running in. So in case the same app is running on Ice Cream Sandwhich (API level 15) , the same toggle button should look like this :

[image]

Does android provide any means to support this feature without building different a apk for each API level?

Comment: Any new on my answer? Have you tried to work with API level 16?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit*

- You need to work with sdk level 16 (or the latest), so the Switch
  class will be recognized
- set android:minSdkVersion to 8 in the
  manifest
- work with folders like stated below:

---

You have to use different layout that you will put in different layout folder.

For the api level 8 (and above), put it in

**/res/layout-v8**
and use the ToggleButton class: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

For the level 15:

**/res/layout-v15**
and use a Switch class.

Good readings for you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: Though this is the closest one can get, I suppose, without any customizations, it still does not work. You see, my app has min API Level defined as 8. So even though I can create API-specific resources, when I declare a 'switch' in my code,it is not recognized since it was never there in API level 8. Is there any way to by-pass this situation, like using a parent class to cascade the view?

Comment: Develop with API level 16, even if your min API is level 8. I don't know why people still want to develop with older SDK.

Comment: Actually, I am working on a very basic utility app. And since Gingerbread still runs in more than 50% of the Android devices, I decided to keep the min sdk level at 8. How do I develop using API level 16 when the min sdk level is 8? Classes like 'Switch' won't be identified by API level 8.

Comment: "How do I develop using API level 16 when the min sdk level is 8" Create an app with a adk level 16 and set android:minSdkVersion to 8 that's the answer and that's what you HAVE TO do if you want to make it work, trust me, this will work like a charm!